# How to know the live environment of a zend view script (xxx.phtml)

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework

Which object I can use and which function I can call in a zend view script file.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what variables you can access in a view file, you can get them as follows:

```
<?php

    var_dump($this->getVars());

    // or 

    var_dump(get_object_vars($this));

?>
```